# Find $\bar{z}_1b+z_2\bar{b}$ if $z_1$ is the reflection of $z_2$ through $\bar{b}z+b\bar{z}=c$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Let $\bar{b}z+b\bar{z}=c,b\neq0$ be a line in the complex plane. If a point $z_1$ is the reflection of a point $z_2$ through the line, then prove that $\bar{z}_1b+z_2\bar{b}=c$

**My Attempt**
$$
\bar{b}z+b\bar{z}-c=0\\
d_1=d_2\implies\frac{\bar{b}z_1+b\bar{z}_1-c}{2|b|}=\frac{\bar{b}z_2+b\bar{z}_2-c}{2|b|}\\
\bar{b}z_1+b\bar{z}_1=\bar{b}z_2+b\bar{z}_2\\
$$

How do I proceed further and prove the required expression ?

Comment: $d_1=d_2$ does not imply the desired property. You also need the line through $z_1,z_2$ perpendicular to the given line.

Comment: $c$ is a real number (as sum of conjugate numbers). Your condition amounts to $a)$ The midpoint of $z_1$ and $z_2$ is on the line. If you plug in the eq. of the line you get
$\bar z_1+\bar bz_2+b\bar z_2+\bar bz_1=2c$
and $b)$ $z_1-z_2$ is parallel to $b$. That is, $z_1-z_2=db$ for some real $d$. These two conditions combined are equivalent to $z_1$ being the reflection of $z_2$ so you should get the desired conclusion after some algebra (observe that, for example, $z_1\bar b-z_2\bar b$ is a real number, etc.)

Comment: @GReyes $$b\bar{z}_1+\bar{b}z_1+b\bar{z}_2+\bar{b}z_2=2c\implies2\Re(\bar{z}_1b+z_2\bar{b})=2c\implies\Re(\bar{z}_1b+z_2\bar{b})=c$$How does this imply $\bar{z}_1b+z_2\bar{b}=c$ ?

Comment: Since $z_1=z_2+db$ for some real $d$, the combination $\bar z_1b+z_2\bar b=\bar z_2 b+db\bar b+z_2\bar b$ which is real, because it is the sum of two conjugate numbers $\bar z_2 b+z_2\bar b$ and the real number $db\bar b=d|b|^2$. Therefore  you can remove the $\cal{R}$ from your last relation. You need to use both conditions $(a)$ and $(b)$ I mentioned  in my previous comment, since both together are equivalent to your condition of being reflected images w.r.t. the given line.

Answer (score 1):

Since $z_1=z_2+db$ for some real $d$, the combination $\bar z_1b+z_2\bar b=\bar z_2b+db\bar b+z_2\bar b$ which is real, because it is the sum of two conjugate numbers $\bar z_2b+z_2\bar b$ and the real number $db\bar b=d|b|^2$. Therefore you can remove the real part $\mathcal{R}$ from your last relation. You need to use both conditions $(a)$ and $(b)$ I mentioned in my previous comment, since both together are equivalent to your condition of being reflected images w.r.t. the given line.